# Staus NOTRUN in Automatic task scheduler

Tags: db2, scheduled-tasks, db2-luw

I created a DB2 task to run my stored procedure automatically at a specific time,  I created the task using the ADMIN_TASK_ADD procedure:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD ( 'WR_AM_ADT_AUTO_CNRRM_SCHDLR', 
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  '05 16 * * *',
                                  'ASPECT',
                                  'WR_AM_ADT_AUTO_CNRRM',
                                  '81930',NULL,NULL);
                                  
                                  COMMIT;
```

I want to run my scheduled task every day at 04:05 PM, but it didn't work and giving the status as

> NOTRUN, SQLCODE -104

So can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I also checked my scheduler in task list using following command:

```
SELECT * from SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST
```

I am using DB2 9.7 version on Windows.

Comment: Silly question, but I must ask: Did you enable the scheduler?

Comment: yes i enabled it, and its not a silly question. do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status of the task `NOTRUN` means an error prevented the scheduler from calling the task's procedure. The `SQLCODE` indicates the type of error.

I suggest you the followings;

Confirm scheduler is enabled.

```
db2 > db2set
DB2_ATS_ENABLE=YES
```

`ATS` depends on the `SYSTOOLSPACE` tablespace to store historical data and configuration information. You can check if the tablespace exists in your system with the following query.

```
db2 select TBSPACE from SYSCAT.TABLESPACES where TBSPACE = 'SYSTOOLSPACE'
```

You can test stored procedure in isolation

```
CALL WR_AM_ADT_AUTO_CNRRM()
```

Then run your task in schedular!